# Restructure huge unnormalized mysql database

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, database-schema

Hi I have a huge unnormalized mysql database with (~100 million) urls (~20% dupes) divided into identical split tables of 13 million rows each.

I want to move the urls into a normalized database on the same mySql server.

The old database table is unnormalized, and the url's have no index
It look like this:

```
entry{id,data,data2, data3, data4, possition,rang,url}
```

And i'm goin to slit it up into multiple tables.

```
url{id,url}
data{id,data}
data1{id,data}
etc
```

The first thing I did was

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO newDatabase.url (url)
SELECT DISTINCT unNormalised.url FROM oldDatabase.unNormalised
```

But the " SELECT DISTINCT unNormalised.url" (13 million rows) took ages, and I figured that that since "INSERT IGNORE INTO" also do a comparison, it would be fast to just do a

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO newDatabase.url (url)
SELECT unNormalised.url FROM oldDatabase.unNormalised
```

Without the DISTINCT, is this assumption Wrong?

Any way it still takes forever and i need some help, is there a better way of dealing withe this huge quantity of unnormalized data?
Whould it be best if i did a  SELECT DISTINCT unNormalised.url" on the entire 100 milion row database, and exported all the id's, and then moved only those id's to the new database with lets say a php script?

All ideas are welcomed, i have no clue how to port all this date without it taking a year!

ps it is hosted on a rds amazon server.

Thank you!

Comment: Select distinct on such a massive dataset will take very long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [MySQL Manual states](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html) that `LOAD DATA INFILE` is quicker than `INSERT`, the fastest way to load your data would be:

```
LOCK TABLES url WRITE;
ALTER TABLE url DISABLE KEYS;
LOAD DATA INFILE 'urls.txt'
    IGNORE
    INTO TABLE url
    ...;
ALTER TABLE url ENABLE KEYS;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

But since you already have the data loaded into MySQL, but just need to normalize it, you might try:

```
LOCK TABLES url WRITE;
ALTER TABLE url DISABLE KEYS;
INSERT IGNORE INTO url (url)
    SELECT url FROM oldDatabase.unNormalised;
ALTER TABLE url ENABLE KEYS;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

My guess is that `INSERT IGNORE ... SELECT` will be faster than `INSERT IGNORE ... SELECT DISTINCT` but that's just a guess.

Comment: Thank for the input, Will try it But can u expand on why i need to disable keys,  Will it make it faster?

Comment: If I disable the keys,  Whould it not ignore the uniqe constraint and start inserting dupe entry?

Comment: From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html: This feature can be activated explicitly for a MyISAM table. ALTER TABLE ... DISABLE KEYS tells MySQL to stop updating nonunique indexes. ALTER TABLE ... ENABLE KEYS then should be used to re-create missing indexes. MySQL does this with a special algorithm that is much faster than inserting keys one by one, so disabling keys before performing bulk insert operations should give a considerable speedup. Using ALTER TABLE ... DISABLE KEYS requires the INDEX privilege in addition to the privileges mentioned earlier.

Comment: Are your tables MyISAM, or InnoDB?